# How to store and retrieve files in/from android app space?

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage

I'm developing a cordova/phonegap app. Right now, I'm testing the app on Android.

If I include files (audio, video, ...) by default, I can access to that files indicating the "url" like audio/filesong.mp3 or video/filevideo.mp4.

But if I download files with the next code:

```
function downloadFile() {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI("UrlOfTheFile");
    var fileURL = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/appcustomstorage/";
    fileTransfer.download(
    uri, fileURL + "file.extension", function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }, false, {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    });
}
```

I download the file in StorageRoot/appcustomstorage/file.extension

It is possible to store the file in the app package, i.e., in, for example, Android/data/com.example.app??
Or a method to get the Android/data/com.example.app url and then add the necessary folder?

**Solution:**
In this case I find all mp3 in the device. It works on Nexus 4.

index.html

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="ulsongs">
        </ul>
```

index JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}


function gotFS(fileSystem) {
   FileSystem = fileSystem;
   // Call to start to find all files
   getFileSystem();
}
```

storageScript:

```
   var FileSystem = null;
   var AudioExtensions = [ '.mp3' ];// , '.wav', '.m4a' ];
   var my_media = null;
   function listDir(directoryEntry, level) {
    if (level === undefined)
        level = 0;
    var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();

    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) { // success get files and
        // folders
        for ( var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
            if (entries[i].name === '.')
                continue;
            if (entries[i].isDirectory) {    
                FileSystem.root.getDirectory(entries[i].fullPath.slice(1,
                        entries[i].fullPath.length), {
                    create : false
                }, function(dirEntry) {
                    listDir(dirEntry, level + 1);
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('ERROR');
                    alert(error.code);
                });
            }
            if (entries[i].isFile) {

                var extension;
                extension = entries[i].name.substr(entries[i].name
                        .lastIndexOf('.'));
                if (entries[i].isFile === true
                        && $.inArray(extension, AudioExtensions) >= 0) {

                    // Add a song to the list
                    $("#ulsongs").append(
                            "<li id='" + entries[i].fullPath + "'"
                                    + " data-icon=\"audio\"><a>"
                                    + entries[i].name + "</a></li>");
                    $('#ulsongs').listview('refresh');
                }
            }
        }
    }, function(error) { // error get files and folders
        alert('Error. Code: ' + error.code);
    });

    // Action listener
    $('#ulsongs li').click(function(e) {
        pathsong = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log('item clicked. Path: ' + pathsong);
        if (typeof (pathsong) != 'undefined' && pathsong != null) {
            // Stop previous song
            if ((audio_status != null) && (audio_status == 2)) {
                console.log('STOP AUDIO');
                my_media.stop();
                my_media.release();
            }

            // Play the audio file at url
            my_media = new Media(pathsong,
            // success callback
            function() {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
            },
            // error callback
            function(err) {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
            }, status);

            // Play audio
            my_media.play();
        }
    });
}

var audio_status = null;
function status(stat) {
    audio_status = stat;
}

/**
 * 
 */
function getFileSystem() {
    console.log('entra getFileSystem');
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function(fileSystem) { // success get file system
                var sdcard = fileSystem.root;
                sdcard.getDirectory('', {
                    create : false
                }, function(dirEntry) {
                    listDir(dirEntry);
                }, function(error) {
                    alert(error.code);
                })
            }, function(evt) { // error get file system
                console
                        .log('ERROR GETTING FILE SYSTEM'
                                + evt.target.error.code);
            });
}
```

I create a list of mp3.
I use jQuery and jQueryMobile

**Edit**
The process may need a bit of time. It is recommended to show a loading popup.